# Can someone explain this structure: no more ... than? What does it mean here?

Tags: meaning

In the second place, if interpersonal relations, the life of the married couple and the family, love and friendship, may be thought of as belonging to the base of the personality, it must not be forgotten that the base is naturally **no more the whole of the personality than of society**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of “no more______ than _______” is commonly used to link a not-as-obvious fact to an obvious fact, often to the point of caricaturization. Thus, if you want to forcefully claim that something is not so, you might compare it in this way to something that is very obviously not so. For example if you are really bad at playing music you might say “I am no more a musician than I am a tree”. I.e. just like you are obviously not a tree, you are not a musician.

In the case here, the specific comparison is that just as the base does not make up the entirety of society, it also does not make up the entirety of one’s personality.